# Can businesses send money to users with apple pay?

Tags: ios, apple-pay

A business with an iOS App needs to pay its users (the users perform work for the business using the app). Can that business pay its users with Apple Pay? Clearly Apple Pay can be used for peer to peer payments, but my searches are not revealing to me whether or not this is available for Business-to-User payments and whether there is an API for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. My business has a business credit card that’s activated on Apple Pay and that works for depositing funds into Apple Pay Cash as well as Square Cash. And when Apple Cash is low, the debit card will fund sending monies.

I wouldn’t use it for payroll or large payments, but it works well enough to be super handy. There is no API and the payments are iOS and macOS TouchID /FaceID centric.